# Sorting numeric strings

Tags: c#, string, csv, datagridview, int

I'm using `DatagridView` in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) to read a csv file.
The data is not sorting properly when clicking the headers at the top of the grid.

For example, it should be sorted as `1,2,3,4,5,etc`
However, the result is `1,10,2,20,etc`.

I think I need to convert it from a `string` to an `int`, but I don't know how to do that.

Here's my current code:

```
try
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string csvPath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        string rowValue;
       // int rowValue = int.Parse(??);
        string[] cellValue;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        //dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(csvPath))
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(csvPath);
            rowValue = fileReader.ReadLine();
            cellValue = rowValue.Split(',');

            for (int i = 0; i <= cellValue.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                column.Name = cellValue[i];    //column name , value
                column.HeaderText = cellValue[i];
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
               // dataGridView1.Columns[].CellType = typeof(Int64);
            }                      
            while (fileReader.Peek() != -1)
            {
                rowValue = fileReader.ReadLine();
                cellValue =  rowValue.Split(',');
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellValue);
            }
            fileReader.Dispose();
            fileReader.Close();
        }
        else
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to register a comparer into the `DataGridView` like this:

```
private void CustomSortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Column.Name != "ColumnName") return;
         
    var a = int.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString());
    var b = int.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString());

    // If the cell value is already an integer, just cast it instead of parsing    
    e.SortResult = a.CompareTo(b);    
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

and the register the sorter in the `DataGridView`

```
dataGridView1.SortCompare += CustomSortCompare;
```

See the documentation [DataGridView.SortCompare Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ok, thanks...i have new problem...    first column's header  ok 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  good  !   but  others..  have error...

Comment: @Simkyujin You can add a sort comparer in each collumn, so you can verify if it is the collumn that you want like this ````e.Column.Name != "CollumnName"```` and then just return. If it was helpul please dont forget to helpful vote or mark the answer as the correct.

Comment: ok! i will try..  very thank you !  have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code to detect the column of numbers in string mode, convert them to integers and sort them:

```
try {
if (e.Column.Index == 2) {
    e.SortResult = Convert.ToInt32(e.CellValue1) < Convert.ToInt32(e.CellValue2) ? -1 : 1;
    e.Handled = true;
    }

  } catch (Exception ex) {
  }
```

In the above sample, the numbers are in the column 2 of Datagridview.
Put the code into the SortCompare event of grid.

Comment: emm.....not adjust..sorry, i'm C# beginner